# How to sort a React state array?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to sort a react state array which contains data from json file. The format of data in json is:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Rob Don",
    "popularity": 84,
    "id": "da6"
  },
  {
    "name": "Henry Black",
    "popularity": 34,
    "id": "138"
 },
 {
    "name": "Chris Smith",
    "popularity": 56,
    "id": "39c"
 },...]
```

The code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import data from '../resources/myData.json';

class HOME extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {  
        person: [...data.slice(0, 5)]
    };
}
//SOME MORE CODE
```

I tried using the below logic but it doesn't work. I don't know why?

```
onSortChange = () => {
    this.state.person.sort((a, b) => 
        (a.name.toLowerCase() - b.name.toLowerCase())?-1:1
     )
}
```

My question is how do I sort `this.state.person` based on name?

Comment: You're missing your call to `this.setState(...)`

Comment: `(a.name.toLowerCase() - b.name.toLowerCase())` is engough no need the ternary operator and remaining (?-1:1), also setState after sort

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the comparison operator (`> 0`)

Try below

```
this.state.person.sort((a, b) =>
    a.name.toLowerCase() - b.name.toLowerCase() > 0 ? -1 : 1
);
```

To set the output to the state, you need to use `setState` method

```
onSortChange = () => {
    this.setState((state) => {
        if(Array.isArray(state.person)){
            return {
                person: state.person.sort((a, b) =>
                 a.name.toLowerCase() - b.name.toLowerCase() > 0 ? -1 : 1;
             }
        }
        return state;
    });
};
```

Comment: @Aditya Mishra, check this out !!

Comment: As reported [here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) using `this.state` into `this.setState` is wrong and could cause a non-state update. Better use `this.setState(function(state, props) { return ... })`

Comment: @Aditya Mishra, updated the answer

Comment: No change in state.person.